# Accord ou pas avec « sembler être [adjectif] » ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, accord, attributs

Voici une phrase :

> Les gens ne semblent plus être intéressés.

Est-il correct de faire l'accord de l'adjectif *intéressé* ?

Comment: Accord après [être](http://www.logilangue.com/public/Site/clicGrammaire/AccordApresEtre.php). Pour être sur, il suffit de tester *Elle me semble être grande*. On accorde grand, donc on accorde intéressé.

Comment: @GautierC OK. En fait, peut on aussi dire *Les gens ne semblent plus intéressés*?

Comment: oui, je suis en train de chercher une explication plus poussée

Comment: Tu n'es pas obligé de mettre être d'ailleurs *les gens ne semblent plus intéressés* est tout à fait correct.

Comment: @GautierC le truc de mettre au féminin ne marche que pour des locuteurs francophones !  Sinon il vaut mieux renvoyer à l'accord du participe passé avec les verbes d'état. Le participe passé conjugué avec   un verbe d'état (*être* *sembler, *paraitre*, *devenir*,  *demeurer*, *rester*) s'accorde (en genre et en nombre) avec le nom auquel il se rapporte. « intéressé » se rapporte à « les gens » donc on met le pluriel.

Comment: @Laure oui c'est ce que je me disais ^^ d'où ma recherche dont j'allais écrire la solution mais tu m'as devancé ! :)

Comment: @GautierC  Et je n'ai pas fait de réponse parce que je suis sûre que c'est déjà sur FL pas trouvé mais c'était pus rapide d'écrire la règle que de chercher...

Comment: @Laure pas faux. A clore donc ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Sembler** (par extension, sembler être) est l'un des rares **verbes d'état** (avec être, rester, demeurer, passer pour, et quelques autres)

En conséquence, il est suivi par un **attribut du sujet** qui est un adjectif, lequel est rattaché et s'accorde au sujet.
Si le sujet est pluriel, on l'accorde alors au pluriel.

La phrase correcte est bien

> Les gens ne semblent plus être intéressés.